# Как реализовать одностороннюю связь при помощи Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, связи

Здраствуйте, есть вопрос касательно hibernate. Предположим, что есть 2 сущности - Entity1 и Entity2. Есть ли способы связать эти сущности таким образом, что бы Entity1 имела экземпляр класса Entity2, а Entity2 не имела экземпляра Entity1 нет, пользуясь при этом OneToOne связью:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {

    @OneToOne
    private Entity2 entity2;

}

@Entity
public class Entity2 {
    //Эта сущность не имеет поля, ссылающегося на Entity2
}
```

Comment: Перечитайте свой вопрос. А так-то Вы уже связали entity1 с entity2 в одностороннем порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть. Вот пример.

**Entity1:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entity1")
public class Entity1 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_id")
    private Entity2 entity2;

    public Entity2 getEntity2() {
        return entity2;
    }

    public void setEntity2(Entity2 entity2) {
        this.entity2 = entity2;
    }

    public Entity1() {
    }
}
```

**Entity2:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entity2")
public class Entity2 {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Entity2() {
    }

    //... getters and setters
}
```

В таблице *entity1* будет создан внешний ключ на *entity2*.